# error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure!

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-community, magento-connect

Whenever I try to install an extension on Magento via **SSH** or via **Magento Connect** (/downloader) the following error happens:

> error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure!

This happens on all versions from `1.5 - 1.9.1.0.`

This happens with any extension.

Comment: So do they plan on fixing it server-side anytime soon? I've seen this affecting many Magento Connect installs.

Comment: They can't fix it server side because that would require them to turn SSLv3 back on which is a security risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have received a version of the:

`error: 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure!` error while trying to install a Magento Connect extension, it's because Magento turned off SSLv# on Magento Connect, but curl is still trying to connect with SSLv3. 
Here is a solution we came up with a few days ago - I wrote about it on our blog: https://www.dwdonline.com/blog/fix-magento-error14077410ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure.html

Comment: Shouldn't Magento fix this server-side somehow? They changed the way a service functions (obviously with consideration to security) but by doing so they broke their service for many users. I've experienced it a few times now with clients on production environment.

Comment: It's not possible. The only way for them to fix this on their side is 1, turn SSLv3 back on (bad choice as it's a major security risk), or 2, they could (and probably will) release a patch - much like mine, or 3, they will fix it in 1.9.1.x. Until then the only way it to patch it as I've mentioned. They will probably release a patch (much like mine) I'm supposing. In fact, I've been in contact about that.